# Vee-validate and vuetify checkbox group with v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I have some problem with vee-validate, vuetify and v-for.
There is my code :

```
<ValidationProvider
  name="availableLanguages"
  rules="required"
  v-slot="{ errors }"
>
  <v-row>
    <v-col
      cols="2"
      v-for="availableLanguage in availableLanguages"
      :key="availableLanguage.label"
    >
      <v-checkbox
        v-model="selectedLanguage"
        :label="availableLanguage.label"
        :value="availableLanguage.value"
        :error="errors.length > 0"
        hide-details
        @click="setDefaultLanguage"
        key="availableLanguage-input"
      />
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <v-col
      cols="12"
      class="errorCheckBox"
    >
      {{ errors[0] }}
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</ValidationProvider>
```

What is the expected result ?

I have a checkbox group. I want if all checkboxes are unchecked then an error message appear.

What's happened ?

If i don't click once on the first iteration of the v-for loop, the error is not trigger.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Validationprovider doesn't validate as soon as form is rendered, but only does it when the field has been touched. You can use `immediate` prop to make the field be validated when rendered:

```html
<ValidationProvider
  name="availableLanguages"
  rules="required"
  immediate
  v-slot="{ errors }"
>
```

Comment: It works thank you ! I thougth that the aggressive mode does it but it don't.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it works! If it solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer. Have a great weekend and happy coding :)